# Conditional Formatting XSL

Tags: parsing, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-2.0

I'm trying to make `<sup>` elements superscripted when I encounter them. I'm iterating over a large file which I can include if required, basically `<xml><article><body><p><em></em><sup></sup></p></body></article></xml>`

I'm receiving:

> Error reported by XML parser: The element type "fo:inline" must be terminated by
>     the matching end-tag "`</fo:inline>`"

when trying to use the below to raise the superscripts:

```
<xsl:for-each select="*">
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:if test="name() = 'sup'">
            <fo:inline vertical-align='super' baseline-shift='4pt'>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="xhtml"/>
        <xsl:if test="name() = 'sup'">
            </fo:inline>
        </xsl:if>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:for-each>
```

How can I correct this so the `vertical-align='super'` is only for `sup` elements; and is there a better approach to this? I plan to do the same for `em`s later.

My code which I use currently but puts everything out as plain text is:

```
<xsl:for-each select="*">
    <fo:block><xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="xhtml"/></fo:block>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to transform `<sup></sup>` to `<fo:inline vertical-align='super' baseline-shift='4pt'></fo:inline>` then the usual way with XSLT is to set up a template

```
<xsl:template match="sup">
  <fo:inline vertical-align='super' baseline-shift='4pt'>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </fo:inline>
</xsl:template>
```

I am not sure whether you want to do that in general or for a particular mode (in that case add `mode="mode-name"` on the `xsl:template` and `mode="#current"` on the `xsl:apply-templates`).